# AD Roles based Authorization in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

In our MVC3 based Intranet app, one AD User may belong to many roles and during login, they will choose the role they want to login as. We are currently authenticating the user using the following approach: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#35

Once the user is authenticated and found to belong to the role they are trying to login as, we would like to authorize access to specific Controllers and Actions based on their Role. We would prefer to use the Authorize attribute of the MVC.

Since we are not using any providers to autnenticate, can we still somehow use the Authorize attribute to restrict access?

Thanks!
Bala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Authorize attribute as long as your custom membership provider inherits from the asp.net MemberShipProvider class.

But if you decide to have an entirely new provide which doesn't inherit from asp.net MembershipProvider class than you can't use the Authorize attirbute.

Answer (score 0):

@Pankaj is right but You can define you'r custom Attribute for exam: `class MyAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter` and override OnAuthorization method of it. then decorate each action with this custom attribute and calculate authorization in body of OnAuthorization. this is a sample:

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public string _name;

        public MyAuthorizationAttribute(string name)
        {
           this._name = curPerm.name;
        }


        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
          // Calculate permissions...
          if (!permit)
          {               
             Exception e = new MethodAccessException("Access to partial denied!");
             throw new Exception("Can't access via address bar!", e);
          }
        }
}
```

and use in action

```
[MyAuthorizationAttribute ("Add")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "About page";

    return View();
}
```

Hope this useful.
Good luck.